Bitrix24 вызов попапа посредством события в inti.php
В init.php прописываю событие, которое должно открывать попап после сообщения в открытых линиях, само событие отрабатывает, в лог пишет. Но попап в CRM не открывается. Вот само событие:
 AddEventHandler("imopenlines", "OnSessionStart", "OnFirstMessage"); 
  function OnFirstMessage($arFields) {
       $chatId = $arFields['CHAT_ID']; // Логируем ID чата в файл для дальнейшей обработки
         file_put_contents(__DIR__."/test.txt", $chatId . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                \Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addString('
                <div id="openline_confirm"></div>'); 
            \Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset::getInstance()->addString('
                <script>
                  BX.ready(function() {
                    var Confirmer = new BX.PopupWindow("openline_confirm", null, {
                      content: "<div></div>" + "<h3>Новое сообщение в открытых линиях</h3>",
                      closeIcon: {
                        right: "20px",
                        top: "20px"
                      },
                      width: 350, // ширина окна
                      height: 150, // высота окна
                      zIndex: 100, // z-index
                      draggable: false, // можно двигать или нет
                      resizable: true, // можно ресайзить
                      min_height: 250, // минимальная высота окна
                      min_width: 100, // минимальная ширина окна
                      overlay: {
                        backgroundColor: "black",
                        opacity: "80"
                      },
                      buttons: [
                        new BX.PopupWindowButton({
                          text: "Принять",
                          className: "popup-window-button-accept",
                          events: {
                            click: function() {
                              BX.Messenger.Public.openLines();
                              this.popupWindow.close();
                            }
                          }
                        }),
                        new BX.PopupWindowButton({
                          text: "Отклонить",
                          className: "webform-button-link-cancel",
                          events: {
                            click: function() {
                              this.popupWindow.close();
                            }
                          }
                        })
                      ]
                    });
                    Confirmer.show();
                  });
                </script>');
    CJSCore::Init(array("Confirmer")); 
}

При событии js на стороне клиента не добавляется, как это можно реализовать?
